# How to verify cross account AWS S3 bucket exists or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have an application using aws account A which needs to check if bucket in aws account B exists or not. If the bucket doesn't exist then I want the application to fail at the start.

I have setup `"s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetObject", "s3:GetBucketLocation"` for a bucket in account B to account A. I was using below to get all the buckets and then looping over the list to match bucket name of account B. I know this will only give list of buckets owned by account A only.

```
s3Client = s3.New(session)
list, err := s3Client.ListBuckets(nil)
```

what is the best way to figure out if bucket in account B exists or not here?

Here is the bucket policy on the bucket in Account B:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<accountA_no>:root"
    },
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "<AccountB_bucket_arn>/*",
        "<AccountB_bucket_arn>"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Will Account B be granting your AWS Account any access rights to the bucket? Or will the bucket in Account B have a Bucket Policy that makes it accessible to other accounts? How will you be using this bucket, if it _does_ exist?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Account B bucket policy as below. Moreover, I am able to read messages using awscli from Account B bucket with Account A credentials exported.  


` {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<accountA_no>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "<AccountB_bucket_arn>/*",
                "<AccountB_bucket_arn>"
            ]
        }`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Also, Application will throw an error when it finds a bucket does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that we can't list cross-account buckets(s3Client.ListBuckets(nil)). It will only return list of buckets owned by an authenticated user. Refer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-cross-account-access/

I updated the code to use ListObjectsV2 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjectsV2.
Before using ListObjectsV2 function, I set up IAM role policy on account A as below which was missing.

```
   {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::account-B-Bucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::account-B-Bucket"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that simply listing a bucket can indicate whether a bucket exists vs does not exist:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://example-bucket

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

$ aws s3 ls s3://example-bucketzz

An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

I'm not a Go person, but from Python I got these results:

```py
>>> len(list(boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('example-bucket').objects.all()))

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

>>> len(list(boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('example-bucketzz').objects.all()))

botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```